# System fonts don't display in Pages 5.5

Tags: pages, font

As much as I hate the new Pages, I use it because it was a resource all my devices could update/re-upload before Microsoft Office came out on iOS devices. However, there are some fonts missing that are clearly OS installed.

Furthermore, it's valid, in my Font Book and in my System > Library > Fonts folder. I use it in Xcode and am trying to create a PDF in Pages to include in my application, so naturally, keeping the same font would be fluid and professional. However, it's not displaying as an option to choose and there is no preferences settings for fonts and I've tried repairing disk as a just-in-case measure. All my custom installed fonts display as an option to choose in pages but not select system fonts. **this is not pages in iCloud** Any suggestions?

EDIT: Not that it would matter, because it's more than this one specific font, but the font in question is 'Heiti TC Light' [an OS installed Font]. I just know I'll get a comment asking this. But again, it's more than this one.

Comment: Heiti is intended only for Chinese text.  Is that what you are using it for?  It is a bad idea to use it for anything else.

Comment: Do you not see your "missing" fonts in Format > Font > Show Fonts?

Comment: Ahhh good point @TomGewecke  care to offer it as an answer to receive credit. And I don't see it as a poor choice for a simple PDF. I also don't think it causes any issues as it's an approved font for developing, for an app I've developed a year ago with no issues, users feedback on it, or memory leaks, layout, or any other fallbacks, as of yet. Could change but as of now it's showing no cons to using it for my intended purposes.

Comment: Fine if it works for you.  The reasons not to use such fonts for latin text in general are a) the latin part of such fonts often has errors somewhere which make for wrong display of individual characters, b) it's 34MB if you wind up embedding the whole thing someplace, and c) a non-mac platform will likely substitute yet another Chinese font which could have its own problems.

Comment: Yeah it's not very layout friendly in Pages but just trying to create an overall fluid layout for the app and it's related resources. No issues as of yet, not even with localized strings. I have users in Sweden etc that have not shared an issues. But I'm not disagreeing with you, just saying as of now it hasn't proved unreliable @TomGewecke

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try looking for these fonts in Format > Font > Show Fonts.  That should always give you a full list even if the dropdown menu inside Pages for some reason does not.